# How to access just the changed data of an 'input' event regardless of text deletion or insertion like pasted or typed or restored text for the latter?

Tags: javascript, input, text, event-handling, custom-events

I have a textarea and would like to return the most recent change to the text for use in avia JavaScript function. That would include:

- Text that is input via keyboard, paste, or inserted via widget (oninput, perhaps?)
- Text that is removed via backspace, delete, ctrl + backspace, etc.

For example:

- If the user presses "a" that is what I want to return.
- If they paste "apple" I want that whole pasted phrase.
- If they hit backspace and delete "h" I want that returned.
- If they highlight "horse" and press delete,

I'm still new to this and have no real idea how to call that added/removed text for use in a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading about [`InputEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent), [`InputEvent.inputType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType) and [`InputEvent.data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/data) might be a good starting point. In combination with `selectionStart` / `selectionEnd` as with e.g. [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)s and/or [`HTMLTextAreaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement)s one pretty much could cover/solve the OP's task.

A possible approach which detects (text) changes within the input data/value might ...

- utilize a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) instance as textarea and/or input-element based ***storage*** for such an element's most recent (text) value.
- enable the exact detection of data/value-changes by keeping track of such an element's ***`'input'` events***, based on the most recent and the current (text) values as well as on `selectionEnd` and sometimes on the input event's `data` value.
- In case of having verified an input-event based text-value change ***a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) is created and dispatched***. Thus one now can ***directly listen to and handle textarea and/or input-element related `'input:datachange'` events***.

On top of the new custom `'input:datachange'` event type, with all the additional information one does neither receive by `'input'` nor by `'change'` events, **the OP now will be able to directly access the changed value whether *deleted and/or inserted*** (pasted or typed or restored for the latter).

```js
// the node reference based storage of most recent element values.
const mostRecentValueStorage = new WeakMap;

function getDataChangeFromDeleteOrPaste({ currentTarget, data }) {
  const recentValue = mostRecentValueStorage.get(currentTarget);
  const { value: currentValue, selectionEnd } = currentTarget;

  let deletionStart = selectionEnd;
  let leadingValue = currentValue.slice(0, deletionStart);

  while ((leadingValue !== '') && !recentValue.startsWith(leadingValue)) {
    leadingValue = leadingValue.slice(0, --deletionStart);
  }
  const deletionLength =
    (selectionEnd - deletionStart) + (recentValue.length - currentValue.length);

  const deleted = recentValue.slice(deletionStart, (deletionStart + deletionLength));

  const insertLength = currentValue.length + deleted.length - recentValue.length;
  const insertStart = selectionEnd - insertLength;

  const inserted = (insertStart < selectionEnd)
    && currentValue.slice(insertStart, selectionEnd)
    || null;

  return {
    currentValue,
    recentValue,
    deleted: (deleted === '') ? null : deleted,
    deletionStart: (deleted === '') ? null : deletionStart,
    deletionLength: (deleted === '') ? null : deletionLength,
    inserted,
    insertStart: (inserted === null) ? null : insertStart,
    insertLength: (inserted === null) ? null : insertLength,
  };
}
function getDataChangeFromInsertText({ currentTarget, data }) {
  const recentValue = mostRecentValueStorage.get(currentTarget);
  const { value: currentValue, selectionEnd } = currentTarget;

  const insertLength = data.length;

  const deletionStart = (selectionEnd - insertLength);
  const deletionLength = (recentValue.length - currentValue.length + insertLength);

  const deleted = recentValue.slice(deletionStart, (deletionStart + deletionLength));

  return {
    currentValue,
    recentValue,
    deleted: (deleted === '') ? null : deleted,
    deletionStart: (deleted === '') ? null : deletionStart,
    deletionLength: (deleted === '') ? null : deletionLength,
    inserted: data,
    insertStart: (selectionEnd - insertLength),
    insertLength,
  };
}

function handleCustomInputDataChange(evt) {
  const { currentTarget } = evt;

  if (currentTarget.value !== mostRecentValueStorage.get(currentTarget)) {
    const { data } = evt;

    const dataChange = (
      (typeof data === 'string') && getDataChangeFromInsertText(evt)
    ) || (
      (data === null) && getDataChangeFromDeleteOrPaste(evt)
    ) || null;

    // put the most recent element value into an object based storage.
    mostRecentValueStorage.set(currentTarget, currentTarget.value);

    currentTarget
      .dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('input:datachange', {
          bubbles: true,
          detail: {
            dataChange,
            inputEvent: evt,
          },
        })        
      );
  }
}

function enableCustomInputDataChangeHandling(elmNode) {
  // put the initial element value into an object based storage.
  mostRecentValueStorage.set(elmNode, elmNode.defaultValue);

  elmNode
    .addEventListener('input', handleCustomInputDataChange);
}
function initializeCustomInputDataChangeHandling() {
  document
    // for every element which features a
    // `data-handle-input-data-change` attribute ...
    .querySelectorAll('[data-handle-input-data-change]')

    // ... enable the handling of a custom
    // 'input:datachange' event.
    .forEach(enableCustomInputDataChangeHandling);
}

function main() {
  initializeCustomInputDataChangeHandling();

  document
    // subscribe to the custom 'input:datachange' event wherever it is needed. 
    .addEventListener(
      'input:datachange',
      ({ target, detail: { dataChange } }) => console.log({ /*target, */dataChange })
    );
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 76%; min-height: 100%!important; }
```

```html
<textarea
  data-handle-input-data-change
  cols="16"
  rows="12"
>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ... edit text in whichever way.</textarea>
```

Comment: This is awesome

Comment: Truly incredible. Wish this could be best answer twice.