# How to reliably intercept (and cancel) all the input in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contenteditable, text-processing

I need to catch all the input in my `contenteditable` element and process the input in the code. Basically, what I need is to prevent input event from changing data in element and to know what data was going to be inserted.

I tried out almost every possible event, but all the time I was getting some unexpected behavior.

For example.

First and most obvious - `keydown` event. It works fine for desktop browser, barely works for mobile and absolutely ignores the Input Method Editors (IME, win/meta + .).

The next one was `textInput` event. Same problems, but worked a little bit better with IME.

Now I found out that `beforeInput` is probably the more universal solution. I tried to use it while looking for the `inputType`(which can tell about current action - insertContent, removeWordForward, etc) and `data` properties, but it doesn't work completely in Safari (and I can't debug it for now). Also it is not reliable with IME.

And the bonus round is custom mobile keyboards like Microsoft Swift Keyboard, which has absolutely unpredictable behavior and I don't know how to process that. For example, it can have word autocompletion - there is no information about this in any event.

Maybe there are workarounds? I've tried to check open source repos with text editors and it looks like a really non-trivial task, because I found out that they use every event that I listed and they have a lot of logic to process them

Comment: Did you try the `input` event?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Comment: @James input can't be canceled :(

Comment: The OP might have a look into [_"How to access just the changed data of an 'input' event regardless of text deletion or insertion like pasted or typed or restored text for the latter?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233372/how-to-access-just-the-changed-data-of-an-input-event-regardless-of-text-delet/72240501#72240501) in order to get and/or try some of the ideas/approaches.

Comment: You could try an `input` event and just reset the editable element to its original state whenever something happens? What do you need this for exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the OP's question ...

> *"Basically, what I need is to prevent input event from changing data in element and to know what data was going to be inserted."*

This simply can be achieved by querying all elements which feature a `contenteditable` attribute and in addition are truly *content-editable*.

One would store each element-node's default-state in e.g. a `WeakMap` instance via the node's reference which refers an object that does feature for example the element's original `innerHTML` and `textContent` values.

In case an 'input' event based content-change happens one would immediately restore the default by setting the original `innerHTML` value.

```js
// the node-reference based storage of editable element's text-contents.
const editableContentStorage = new WeakMap;

function suppressEditableTextContentChange(evt) {
  const { currentTarget } = evt;

  const {
    defaultHtml,
    defaultText,
  } = editableContentStorage.get(currentTarget);

  const changedContent = currentTarget.textContent;

  // immediately restore default content.
  currentTarget.innerHTML = defaultHtml;

  console.log({ defaultText, changedContent });
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('[contenteditable]')
  .forEach(elmNode => {
    if (elmNode.contentEditable === 'true') {

      editableContentStorage
        .set(elmNode, {
          defaultHtml: elmNode.innerHTML,
          defaultText: elmNode.textContent,
        });

      elmNode
        .addEventListener('input', suppressEditableTextContentChange);
    }
  });
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
h2 { margin: 5px 0; font-size: 1.1em; }
p { margin: 5px 0; }
article { width: 23%; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 76%; min-height: 100%!important; }
```

```html
<article contenteditable>
  <h2>Some header copy</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>
    The quick <b>brown fox</b> jumps over the
    <b>
      <em>lazy</em>
      dog
    </b>.
  </p>
</article>
```